# Smoke domain position problem blender 3.2.0

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm new to blender
when smoke is made, the smoke appears elsewhere
[image]

I've searched everywhere but can't find anything about it.

This is an example file with the issue: [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I downloaded and ran your file the position for the smoke was as expected...  Smoke will cache its results so as not to use up computation, but sometimes needs coaxing after you make edits, just as move the source to another position.  In these cases, make an edit to your domain parameters, and then you can undo the edit (example increment the Division Resolution and then decrement).  or you can go to your cache folder (in your case //..\..\..\tmp\blender_9PuK4K\cache_fluid_4b85f272) and delete all subfolders to clear the cache.